# SharePoint List Filter WebPart - Advanced Filter Options - Empty values

Tags: sharepoint-list-filter

I want to connect a SharePoint List Filter Web Part to a List View Web part and use the feature to enable users to filter by a null value. In the Advanced Filter Options section, I selected "(Empty)" value.

But when I select (Empty) in the Select Filter Value(s) dialog box, it displays all items after applying the filter.

Any help would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue few years back, and as I remember this is the limitation of CAML query(you need to use IsNull filter instead of Eq), when you use empty value in connected web part, it display all the items.

There is no way to build conditional CAML query, so I was ended up using two web parts, and based on Null filter selection, I show one of it and hide other one.